# compare the records from the recent Monday to the immediate last Monday and flag as old or new for all Mondays existing in the data

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a dataset that has the the different schedule codes by date at a PO number level..I am trying to identify the records from the most recent monday and compare it to the immediate last monday and then flag the combination of (POnumber /schedule_code) to be old (meaning this combination existed the last monday otherwise I have to flag it as new.. I have to consider only the most recent monday and the immediate last monday for consideration for all the monday dates existing in the data

**Input table**

| Date | POnumber | schedule_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7/19/2022 | FD17891 | 3 |
| 7/19/2022 | KL89123 | 15 |
| 7/19/2022 | YU12643 | 5 |
| 7/18/2022 | D78123 | 10 |
| 7/18/2022 | C12678 | 5 |
| 7/18/2022 | J12341 | 2 |
| 7/18/2022 | B12314 | 5 |
| 7/18/2022 | JK1234 | 2 |
| 7/17/2022 | K123121 | 5 |
| 7/17/2022 | V12312 | 4 |
| 7/17/2022 | X12890 | 3 |
| 7/16/2022 | S7832 | 5 |
| 7/16/2022 | F12345 | 5 |
| 7/11/2022 | D78123 | 10 |
| 7/11/2022 | XC12341 | 2 |
| 7/11/2022 | BH1231 | 4 |
| 7/11/2022 | J12341 | 1 |
| 7/11/2022 | C12678 | 5 |
| 7/9/2022 | U12341 | 3 |
| 7/9/2022 | JK12891 | 5 |
| 7/9/2022 | N1290 | 10 |
| 7/8/2022 | I18967 | 5 |
| 7/8/2022 | HJ1230 | 2 |
| 7/7/2022 | F12901 | 3 |
| 7/7/2022 | MF12901 | 4 |
| 7/7/2022 | HE1289 | 5 |
| 7/7/2022 | B1234 | 5 |
| 7/6/2022 | JK1234 | 1 |
| 7/6/2022 | HG7812 | 2 |
| 7/5/2022 | XD1231 | 9 |
| 7/5/2022 | FR1231 | 4 |
| 7/5/2022 | IO8921 | 2 |
| 7/4/2022 | C12678 | 5 |
| 7/4/2022 | J12341 | 4 |
| 7/4/2022 | XC12341 | 2 |
| 7/4/2022 | D78123 | 10 |

**Output table**

| Date | POnumber | schedule_code | New/old |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/18/2022 | D78123 | 10 | Old |
| 7/18/2022 | C12678 | 5 | Old |
| 7/18/2022 | J12341 | 2 | New |
| 7/18/2022 | B12314 | 5 | New |
| 7/18/2022 | JK1234 | 2 | New |
| 7/11/2022 | D78123 | 10 | Old |
| 7/11/2022 | XC12341 | 2 | Old |
| 7/11/2022 | BH1231 | 4 | New |
| 7/11/2022 | J12341 | 1 | New |
| 7/11/2022 | C12678 | 5 | Old |

```
Input table

create table ##input
(snapshotdate date,
ponumber varchar(100),
schedulecode int)

insert into ##input values

('7/19/2022','FD17891','3'),
('7/19/2022','KL89123','15'),
('7/19/2022','YU12643','5'),
('7/18/2022','D78123','10'),
('7/18/2022','C12678','5'),
('7/18/2022','J12341','2'),
('7/18/2022','B12314','5'),
('7/18/2022','JK1234','2'),
('7/17/2022','K123121','5'),
('7/17/2022','V12312','4'),
('7/17/2022','X12890','3'),
('7/16/2022','S7832','5'),
('7/16/2022','F12345','5'),
('7/11/2022','D78123','10'),
('7/11/2022','XC12341','2'),
('7/11/2022','BH1231','4'),
('7/11/2022','J12341','1'),
('7/11/2022','C12678','5'),
('7/9/2022','U12341','3'),
('7/9/2022','JK12891','5'),
('7/9/2022','N1290','10'),
('7/8/2022','I18967','5'),
('7/8/2022','HJ1230','2'),
('7/7/2022','F12901','3'),
('7/7/2022','MF12901','4'),
('7/7/2022','HE1289','5'),
('7/7/2022','B1234','5'),
('7/6/2022','JK1234','1'),
('7/6/2022','HG7812','2'),
('7/5/2022','XD1231','9'),
('7/5/2022','FR1231','4'),
('7/5/2022','IO8921','2'),
('7/4/2022','C12678','5'),
('7/4/2022','J12341','4'),
('7/4/2022','XC12341','2'),
('7/4/2022','D78123','10')


output table

create table ##output
(snapshotdate date,
ponumber varchar(100),
schedulecode int,
neworold text)

('7/18/2022','D78123','10','Old'),
('7/18/2022','C12678','5','Old'),
('7/18/2022','J12341','2','New'),
('7/18/2022','B12314','5','New'),
('7/18/2022','JK1234','2','New'),
('7/11/2022','D78123','10','Old'),
('7/11/2022','XC12341','2','Old'),
('7/11/2022','BH1231','4','New'),
('7/11/2022','J12341','1','New'),
('7/11/2022','C12678','5','Old')
```

**Query tried**

```
WITH CTE AS
 (
  SELECT *,DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY snapshotdate DESC) AS RNum
  FROM ##input
  WHERE DATEADD(DAY,14,snapshotdate)>GETDATE()
    AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY,snapshotdate) = 'Monday'
 )
 SELECT C1.snapshotdate,C1.ponumber,C1.schedulecode
       ,CASE WHEN C2.snapshotdate IS NOT NULL THEN 'Old' ELSE 'New' END AS [Old Or New]
 FROM CTE C1 LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.RNum + 1 =C2.RNum AND C1.ponumber=C2.ponumber AND C1.schedulecode=C2.schedulecode
 WHERE C1.RNum=1
```

Comment: You need to partition the ranking by PO.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f03ab28ad4583163ed7eed20033ad8a5&hide=1

Comment: Hi @shawnt00: Thanks for sharing your dbfiddle...The problem that I am seeing is that for  2022-07-11 all are shown as New

Comment: @shawnt00: I am trying to compare every Monday with its prior Monday

Comment: Maybe this is more what you had in mind: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5c8decbedeedfbbef92cbdf21f4466ab&hide=1

Comment: @shawnt00: Thanks for your response!...My data has dates from Jan 2022 ..So can I list the data for every monday in comparison to the previous monday use the query... I am trying to understand how to modify  snapshotdate > DATEADD(DAY, -20, CAST('20220722' AS DATE)) and C1.snapshotdate > DATEADD(DAY, -13, CAST('20220722' AS DATE) for achieving the above...

Comment: In the inner CTE query you'll want to bring back all the data necessary to complete the calculation. So looking back to the last 7 days of December would be enough. The outer query is then where you filter for results that actually get returned. But ultimately it sounds like the inner query just needs one extra week. If it's parameterized just subtract days from that reference point.

Comment: If you have no gaps the `lag()` will probably be useful. I'm actually not entirely sure how you want your data to display. Here's a query with `lag()` though: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=211cbe78c2d644f0b69286174eed7b12

Comment: @shawnt00: The last dbfiddle absolutely works!...Really appreciate your help! :)...Also I am not able to accept your answer as it is in a comment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with data as (
  select *,
      row_number() over (partition by ponumber order by snapshotdate) as rn,
      lag(schedulecode) over (partition by ponumber order by snapshotdate) as last_sc
  from ##input
  -- report start date adjusted backward to pick up the prior week
  where snapshotdate > dateadd(day, -7, cast('20220101' as date)) -- can use index
    and datename(weekday, snapshotdate) = 'Monday'
)
select snapshotdate, ponumber, schedulecode,
    case when schedulecode <> last_sc
         then 'Old' else 'New' end as "Old Or New"
from data
where last_sc is not null or rn = 1
order by snapshotdate, ponumber;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=da4dd839d11a582b9fcb9a9f62836589&hide=1